# Is there any algorithm for generating 3d clouds?

Tags: algorithm, 3d

So Id love to see an algorithm for generating 3d cloud objects. as realistic as possible. I know that there are [different cloud types](https://web.archive.org/web/20130220071237/http://www.srh.weather.gov/srh/jetstream/synoptic/clouds_max.htm) But I am moust interested in such cloud tupes like

[image: Cumulo-form]
<sub>(source: [weather.gov](http://www.srh.weather.gov/srh/jetstream/synoptic/images/cumulus_type.gif))</sub>
 [image: Strato-form]
<sub>(source: [weather.gov](http://www.srh.weather.gov/srh/jetstream/synoptic/images/stratus_type.gif))</sub>

so can any one point to algorithm or just a C\C++\C#\AS3 or any other language lib that can do such thing?

Comment: Are you looking for 3d models? Or 3d looking 2d images?

Comment: I am looking for algorithm for generating 3d models of clouds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try [Procedural Generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_generation) or even [Particle Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_system).

Here is a page which seems to have a comprehensive list of various cloud generation methods: [Vterrain.Org's page on Clouds](http://vterrain.org/Atmosphere/Clouds/).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a library that implements this, but this SIGGRAPH paper (http://graphics.cs.brown.edu/games/CartoonSmoke/) outlines a method for generating cartoon clouds that look very much like the one you've posted.

Answer (score -2):

You could do that in any language with any drawing library ! For example, in C++ with [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/)

You could also generate it with a 3D modeler as Blender or 3DSMax, depending on what you want to do with it !

However, I don't know if algorithms to generate clouds are freely available, you should give it a shot in Google.