# Make clouds on the fly

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science, game-engine, game-physics

I am trying to procedurally generate clouds and so far I have tried using the Diamond Square Algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm). This works fairly well but it does not shape the output in the shape of a cloud so at the edges it will be flat. Is there a better way algorithm generate clouds or a way to confine the diamond square algorithm to random polygons?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the output here, as well as the code that produced it?

Comment: If you need 3D clouds, then this discussion might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299714/is-there-any-algorithm-for-generating-3d-clouds

Comment: That link was really useful, exactly was I was looking for.